# map lookups function calls Vs caching the lookup as a static variable

Tags: c++, function, stl

function version one, `map stl` lookup once and saved in a local static variable

```
inline const string & dataInputPath()
{
    static string inputpath = Mngr.getStr("input");
    return inputpath;
}
```

function version two, loop up every time we call the function

```
inline const string & dataInputPath()
{
    return Mngr.getStr("input");
}
```

I have the previos two function calls, 
I want to know

1. what is considered more appropriate?
2. pros and cons?
3. which one do you prefer using and why?
4. and if there is a way to cache the result as an rValue `getStr` return type is `const string&`

Answer (score 0):

In the first, once dataInputPath has been called, the value is never updated, even if the value in the map is changed.

I would just retrieve the value from the map directly. Leave it to the calling code to cache the value in a sensible way, if necessary.

As key "input" is hardcoded, why not just have global input_string variable?

Comment: I have only 4 keys, so next step is moving it to be an enum key. mapValue never change though